# Hiding scroll bar during animations the CSS way

Tags: css

I have some animations which I use for the purpose of transition. Although the transition is cool, it brings up the horizontal and vertical scrollbars which is pretty ugly.

```
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s;
}

.bounce-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Is there any where to define to the browser using CSS that no scrollbar must be displayed during these animations, or in other words, `Overflow = Hidden WHEN Animating`.

Comment: you can try to use JS and listen to the event : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

Comment: please post your relevant HTML

Comment: I tried to replicate your animation. Have a look at https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/KoLWmm see if it helps any how.